# android.view.InflateException Error inflating class fragment, Binary XML file line #1?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, parcel

Android project gives InflateException error.

And this is the error from the Android Studio Android Monitor:

> --------- beginning of crash
>   07-14 00:03:23.801 13726-13726/com.example.romi.parcelablecreatortest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                           Process: com.example.romi.parcelablecreatortest, PID: 13726
>                                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.romi.parcelablecreatortest/com.example.romi.parcelablecreatortest.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>                                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>                                                                                            Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment
>                                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
>                                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
>                                                                                               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
>                                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:280)
>                                                                                               at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
>                                                                                               at com.example.romi.parcelablecreatortest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)

Here is the code:

activity_main.xml

```
<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="com.example.romi.parcelablecreatortest.MainActivityFragment"
    android:layout="@layout/activity_main_activity_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.romi.parcelablecreatortest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are not initialised  `TopRatedMovieJson[] topRatedMovieJson;`that's why you got `NPE`at

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: storage == null at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.(Arrays.java:38) at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:155) at com.example.romi.parcelablecreatortest.MainActivityFragment.onCreate(MainActivityFragment.java:74)
```

update in `MainActivityFragment's`

```
 public void jsonParser(String json) {

        final String LOG_TAG = MainActivityFragment.class.getSimpleName();

        // The variables that we want from the json file
        final String title = "original_title"; // JSONObject
        final String posterPath = "poster_path"; // JSONObject
        final String synopsis = "overview"; // JSONObject
        final String userRating = "popularity"; // JSONObject
        final String releaseDate = "release_date"; // JSONObject

        // Parsing the json file
        try {
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
            // for is used to cycle through the json array.
            topRatedMovieJson= new TopRatedMovieJson[jsonArray.length()];
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i); // getJSONObject(i) will take onw of the json array with i=0 as its first index
                topRatedMovieJson[i] = new TopRatedMovieJson(
                        jsonObject.getString(title),
                        jsonObject.getString(posterPath),
                        jsonObject.getString(synopsis),
                        jsonObject.getString(userRating),
                        jsonObject.getString(releaseDate)
                );
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I initialize it in onCreate. topRatedMovieJson = new TopRatedMovieJson[1000];

Comment: But it still doesn't solve the InflateException error. Any more solution to try?

Comment: @QuartZ I don't have time for solve your full application's errors . first read full logcat and try to error by yourself . if you got error in other line then edit your question.

Comment: Please try cleaning your project and rebuild it!

Comment: Thanks. I fix it. The problem is in the xml.